# Divide error assembler (dosbox)

Tags: ассемблер

Люди добрые, помогите пожалуйста. При выполнении этой программы выскакивает ошибка divide error. Ошибка в этих строках.

```
    mov ax,num
    mov bx,denom
    div bx
    mov result,ax
```

А это код целиком

```
 .MODEL Large,C
        .data
        Extrn   aaaS:byte,cccS:byte,bbbS:byte,denom:word,num:word,result:word;
        .code
        Public  Lab3S
Lab3s   proc    far
    mov ax,22
    div cccS
    mov bx,ax
    mov ax,3
    mul bbbS                   
    add ax,bx
    mov ah,0
    mov num,ax

        mov bl,36
    mov al,aaaS
    mul cccS
    mov dl,3
    div dl
    sub bl,al
    mov bh,0
    mov denom,bx
    
    mov ax,num
    mov bx,denom
    div bx
    mov result,ax
    
        ret
Lab3S   endp
        end
```

Comment: Есть два варианта - деление на ноль и переполнение. Чтобы узнать что из этого произошло, нужны значения cccS, bbbS, aaaS. Чтобы этого не происходило, надо вставлять проверки в коде.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Инструкция DIV делит не просто АХ на делитель, а пару регистров DX:AX.
Поэтому нужно взять за правило, перед операцией деления обязательно очищать DX. На выходе - в АХ получим целое, а в DX остаток от деления.

```
mov  ax,16
mov  bx,3
xor  dx,dx   ;//<--- очистить DX
div  bx      ;// результат: АХ=5, DX=1
```